# Executing $(window).load() and $(window).resize() in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to resize a couple divs on page load and window resize in drupal 7.

theme.info

```
name = Theme
description = The Theme
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
scripts[] = js/scripts.js

(the rest)
```

scripts.js

```
$(window).load(function() {
    getViewport();

});

$(window).resize(function() {
    getViewport();
});

function getViewport() {    
    alert('function hit');
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
         viewportwidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; 
         viewportheight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = (window.innerHeight - 150) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('sidebar-first').style.height = (window.innerHeight - 50) + 'px';
}
```

But neither load, resize, or the function or getting hit.  I'm sure it's my ignorance of utilizing this in drupal, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I've even tried including my own jquery library in the info file, but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: any error in console? Is jquery loaded or not? Etc...

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about checking that.  Drupal noob, sorry.

Comment: in your browser, press F12 to open console and see if any error message

Comment: TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$(window).load(function() {

Comment: means jquery is not loaded. You have to include it but i'm afraid, i'm not a drupal user. I guess, your path to jquery is not accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No jQuery needed for this code to work, just create some event listeners and kill the `$(window)` method chains.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { getViewport() });
window.addEventListener('resize', function() { getViewport() });
```

### Note:

You'll want to normalize `addEventListener()` if you need to target less than IE9. Something like:

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  // Modern browsers
  window.addEventListener('load', function() { getViewport() });
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() { getViewport() });
} else
  // Browsers that need to die
  window.attachEvent('onLoad', function() { getViewport() });
  window.attachEvent('onResize', function() { getViewport() });
}
```

Comment: ya, seems fair enough... +1

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  Although I would still like to get jquery working in the project at some point.

Comment: You should post your Drupal code to another question so others can help you... unfortunately (or fortunately?) I've never used Drupal.